# Is A+B functionally dependent on C

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

I am currently studying Database Management and we were introduced to the idea of functional dependence:

Let A and B be attributes in a relation. B is considered functionally dependent on A if and only if for every A value you can determine a B value. i.e. `A -> B`

My question:

If this is the case, then given A, B, and C; if C can be evaluated arithmetically using A and B, can you consider C to be functionally dependent on A and B?

That is, `(A/B) = C` <=> `AB -> C`

---

As an example:

Say I have a table containing online order information. It includes the attributes: `PROD_PRICE`, `QTY`, and `TOTAL_PRICE`.
Seeing as the total price can be established by multiplying `PROD_PRICE` by the `QTY` is it accurate to say that `PROD_PRICE` `QTY` → `TOTAL_PRICE`?

Comment: What is your reasoning either way? Research & attempts at answering are expected, especially for homework. Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite your textbook with a bespoke tutorial & do your (home)work & you have shown no research or other effort. See [ask], other [help] links, hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) PS  It's good that you quoted a definition, but it's wrong. What is your textbook name, edition & section & its definition?

Comment: It's confusing to have + in the title & / later on. Also "evaluated arithmetically" is unhelpfully vague. What sort of relationships between the columns are ones that you think imply an FD?

Comment: Your FD definition is wrong. A & B should be attribute sets not attributes.As with set AB in AB -> C. We do talk about an attribute functionally determining or being functionally determined or both when one or both sets contains just 1 attribute. But your question's FD AB -> C with set AB doesn't fit your "definitiion" so you can't use it for that FD. PS You are using A & B for different things--the FD "definition" & your title & division examples. Use different pairs of names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If this is the case, then given A, B, and C; if C can be evaluated arithmetically using A and B, can you consider C to be functionally dependent on A and B?

Yes, by definition of functional dependency. In a functional dependency, in general, you have a set of attributes (the “determinant”) that determines another set (the “determinate”), that is each time in an instance of a relation we found the same value of the determinant the determinate must be equal, and this is true if the determinate is obtained as value of an expression over the determinate, like in your example.

Note that in general you do not know which is the function that produces the determinate from the determinant, simply you know that such a function exists. The functional dependency concept captures this fact, which is very important when representing data.

So, if for every row of a table we have `c=a/b`, then `ab->c`, but for instance, when  `PRODUCT_ID -> PRODUCT_NAME` holds, there is no mathematical function that can derive the latter from the former.